# Templates under openEHR

Tags: hl7, medical, openehr

**Hi to everybody!**

At this moment I'm studying some concepts of the **OpenEHR** model: archetypes, ADL and templates. I found some documentation for the first two concepts (archetypes and ADL). I've downloaded some examples from the web page, I'm checking the CKM Manager to understand how are created archetypes, I've downloaded the workbench, etc.

But I've a lot of questions about **templates** on OpenEHR. And on the web page of the community they explain only a few things ("What's a template?", "Goal of templates" and "Why a template?"). Does anybody know where I can found more information about Templates under OpenEHR? Specially I would like to know the **template definition language** (or equivalent): how to create template, meaning of tags, how to translate templates, etc.

Thanks so much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is openEHR supposed to be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449018/how-is-openehr-supposed-to-be-used)

Comment: Google: "openehr template" gives me among 1st results [openEHR: Working with Templates](http://www.openehr.org/downloads/ADLworkbench/working_with_templates) and hint that Google: "openehr template designer" might show some other interesting results

Comment: @xmojmr I discovered the post a few hours before publish my post. I was learnt many things thanks to that message. But in my case I've a determinate question about "Templates under openEHR". At this time I learnt they're the way to restrict and include archetypes, limit the fields included in an archetype, etc. But I need information about how to "define" a template with OpenEHR without workbench, how understand the language of "templates" under openEHR. Anyway thank you for your reply.

Comment: Templates are like big archetypes. RIght now expressed in another format but the next version of ADL will be able to represent archetypes and templates. There is one big difference: archetypes should be globally valid, while templates have local validity, e.g. are locale dependent, and the same "type" of clinical document can be represented im different ways, while and archetype should represent ONE clinical concept inside ONE archetype.

Comment: @jctd_BDyn please select an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Template is what you should use at a software level while archetypes are related more to the definition of the data handled by software. On a template you'll specify complete clinical documents in just one file, using many archetypes.

I recommend to use Operational Templates (OPT) at software because is just one big XML file with all the data and metadata you need to implement such clinical document (data structure, constraints, terminology).

To create OPTs you need the Template Designer by Ocean Informatics. The schema for templates is here: https://github.com/openEHR/reference-models/blob/master/models/openEHR/Release-1.0.2/XSD/Template.xsd

Maybe an OPT XSD is included in the Template Designer, not sure about this. You can ask on the openEHR email lists where the authors of the tool can give you more info.
So, currently there is no template definition language. But fur the new version of ADL (under development), archetypes and templates will be specified using ADL.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is best on SO to ask a specific question.

You may find these recent discussions as well as previous discussion in the openEHR technical mailing list as well as the implementers mailing list helpful:

[Templates](http://lists.openehr.org/pipermail/openehr-technical_lists.openehr.org/2014-October/008614.html)

[Archetypes](http://lists.openehr.org/pipermail/openehr-technical_lists.openehr.org/2014-October/008521.html)

[Tooling](http://lists.openehr.org/pipermail/openehr-technical_lists.openehr.org/2014-October/008600.html)